# AnimationController animateTo method, always going back to start

Tags: flutter

I am using AnimationController.animateTo method to jump my animation to specific points instantly.

When I pass parameter 'target' with a value of 0.0 to animateTo method, the resulting 'value' property of AnimationController is 0.0. If I pass a parameter 'target' to animateTo method with a value of 0.5, the resulting 'value' property of AnimationController still returns 0.0. I would expect the 'value' property to return 0.5.

```
void _onPlayButtonPressed() {
    final cpm = ScopedModel.of<CpModel>(context);
    if (cpm.started) {
      cpm.stop();
      _animController.stop();

      var targetProgress = cpm.adjustedProgress;
      _animController.animateTo(targetProgress , duration: Duration(seconds: 0));
    } else {
      _ranOnce = true;
      cpm.start();
      _animController.forward();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got late to answer that but will be helpful for other developers.

Add your animation controller onto the Animation object and use that animation object.

Like this:
The following example shows how you can use AnimationController's toAnimate method:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override[![demo][1]][1]
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late Animation<double> slideAnimation;
  late AnimationController sliderAnimationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    sliderAnimationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    slideAnimation = Tween<double>(begin:0, end: 130).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: sliderAnimationController, curve: Curves.ease));
    print(    sliderAnimationController.value);

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: SizedBox(width: 130,height: 160,child: IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      sliderAnimationController.animateTo(0.0);

                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Text1",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .bodyText1!
                            .copyWith(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  12.verticalSpace,
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                      //  sliderAnimationController.forward();
                      sliderAnimationController.animateTo(0.215);
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Text2",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .subtitle1!
                            .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  12.verticalSpace,
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      sliderAnimationController.animateTo(0.405);

                    }
                    ,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Text3",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .subtitle1!
                            .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  12.verticalSpace,
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      sliderAnimationController.animateTo(1.0);

                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Text4",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .subtitle1!
                            .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  AnimatedBuilder(

                    animation: sliderAnimationController,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                      return Transform.translate(offset: Offset(0, slideAnimation.value),
                          child: child);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 3,
                      height: 26,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 1,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sliderAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```